# Android: strange crash on grid scroll

Tags: android, user-interface, gridview, adapter

I'm creating a grid by a standard scheme: `GridView` is set with a custom `BaseAdapter`-derivate:

```
class EventGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar;
    Context context;
    GridView gridView;

    public EventGridAdapter(Context context, GridView gridView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.gridView = gridView;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return 31;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        CalendarItem cell = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            cell = new CalendarItem(context);
            int viewHeight = gridView.getHeight();
            int spacing = 1;
            int height = viewHeight / 5 - spacing; 
            cell.setMinimumHeight(height);
        } else {
            cell = (CalendarItem) convertView;
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

About this line:

```
cell = new CalendarItem(context)
```

By now `CalendarItem` is pure `View`, e.g. everything is commented out, so nothing to cause crash there...

And standard `GridView` output:

```
public class CalendarActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.calendar);

    GridView g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridCalendar);
    g.setAdapter(new EventGridAdapter(this, g));        
}
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridCalendar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
android:verticalSpacing="1dp" 
android:numColumns="7"
android:padding="10dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
/>
```

**What is the problem**:

When I run this code in emulator on ICS 4.0.3, grid is shown perfectly, but when I try to scroll it - program crashes with strange exception:

`D/AndroidRuntime( 1087): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1087): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:585)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:10626)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.View.getDrawingCache(View.java:10476)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2743)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2092)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11083)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3398)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2126)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

When I run the same code in emulator on 2.3.3 - everything is fine!

After some investigation I found the "source" of the problem (-. Look again at `getView` method in `EventGridAdapter`:

```
        int viewHeight = gridView.getHeight();
        int spacing = 1;
        int height = viewHeight / 5 - spacing; 
        cell.setMinimumHeight(height);
```

The problem line is:

```
cell.setMinimumHeight(height);
```

When I change it to:

```
cell.setMinimumHeight(10);
```

... crashes dissapear

But I don't know what do I do wrong? Everything looks logically correct: I need 5 rows.
Also, making `height` lower doesn't help (when all rows are in a view area, e.g. no scroll needed):

```
int height = viewHeight / 7 - spacing;
```

Your advices?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is hear...

```
gridView.getHeight()
```

**why?**
because you will not have the height of the gridview @ the time it just created

you can use this method in either `onWindowfocuschanged` or by using viewTreeobserver

like the one below

```
ViewTreeObserver vto1 = gridView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto1.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // write hear for height

                Log.i(TAG, "from VTO" + gridView.getHeight());
                ViewTreeObserver obs = gridView.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't get height when grid is created! `getView` is called much later!
I tried your approach. It returns the same height. And crashes, of course, still appear...